# Auto sent emails from react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a website created with react and firebase. I would like to auto sent an email to the user address email which is logged on after he click a button. How can i do that?

Comment: 1) Find an email service or host your own 2) send an email through that service to the intended recipient

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions... You could use the ["Trigger Email" extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) for that.

Just configure the extension (follow this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-send-e-mails-using-firebase-extensions-a10d7cd685c2)) and then, each time you want to send an email, create a document in the corresponding Firestore collection when the user clicks on the button. That's it, you are done!